# Windows 10 - how to compress file without creating a parent folder

Tags: windows, zip

In Windows 10,

from power shell, I want to compress a folder without it creating a parent folder inside the zip file

currently I use:

```
Compress-Archive -Path . ../abc.zip
```

Is it possible to create the archive without the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this (didn't test it and I don't even have any window installed, so might not work):

```
gci c:\folder\* | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath c:\abc.zip
```